# Changing v-data-table status when getting RestAPI using axios method

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have made apps and I wanted to change v-data-table's status depend on the customers id.
So I made my sample below. but any status information didn't display.
I used axios to get RestAPI. When id from RestAPI are 1 or 3, showing "supercustomer" in data-table.
Does anyone advise me?

[image: my sample]

```
    <template>
  <v-app>
    <v-data-table 
     dense 
     :headers="headers" 
     :items="items" 
     class="elevation-1">
      <template v-slot:items="{items}">
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.email}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.status}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </template>
      </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
import axios from 'axios'

@Component
export default class AxiosPractice extends Vue {
  items: any=[]
  status:string=''

  headers = [
    { text: 'id', value: 'id' },
    { text: 'name', value: 'name' },
    { text: 'email', value: 'email' },
    { text: 'status', value: 'status' }
  ];
  async mounted() {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments'
    );
    this.items = response.data.map((item:any) => {
      const newStatus =
        item.id === '1' || item.id === '3' ? 'supercustomer' : '';
      return {
        id: item.id,
        email: item.email,
        name: item.name,
        status: newStatus
      };
 });
    if(this.items.id = '1' || '3'){
      return this.status = 'supercustomer'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to show the status:

1. `Status` needs to be a part of `item`, or else the status is going to be the same for all items. So change `<td>{{status}}</td>` to `<td>{{item.status}}</td>`.
   And change `{ text: 'status', value: '' }` to `{ text: "status", value: "status" }`.
2. `this.items.id` is not valid since `this.items` is an array.
3. Also when you check if a value is equal a string you should use `===`, which means equal value and equal type. See more about comparisons here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

What I would do is to add the `status` while mapping the items:

```
this.items = response.data.map(item => {
      const newStatus =
        item.id === '1' || item.id === '3' ? 'supercustomer' : '';
      return {
        id: item.id,
        email: item.email,
        name: item.name,
        status: newStatus
      };
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I really appreciate it.
and I tried to edit my code but it didn't work.
I thought I misunderstood your advise.
I edit my questions code. Could you give me advise?

Comment: codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-darkness-fwhv8?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue
Note that I haven't used typescript, but the core of it should be the same.